# How can I select a different .gitignore file?

Tags: git, github

When I do a

```
  // this is in a bash script
  git add -A .
  git commit -m $a
  git push test master
```

what can I do to select a separate `.gitignore` file. The method above uses `.gitignore` but I want to use a similar file called `.gitignore1`.

How can I specify the .gitignore file to use?

**Function - p1**

```
p1() {
  git config --local core.excludesfile = /Users/a/root/.gitignore1
  a=$1
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
      a=$(timestamp)
  fi
  git add -A .
  git commit -m $a
  git push test master
  echo $a
}
```

**File - .gitignore1**

```
/.DS_Store
/web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an outside file to ignore changes:

```
git config --local core.excludesfile PATH_TO_GITIGNORE1
```

To read more take a look at [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#coreexcludesfile-bNWU0)

**Example:**

`~/.gitignore1` - Ignore a

`~/.gitignore2` - Ignore b

```
$ cat ~/.gitignore1
a
$ cat ~/.gitignore2
b
```

`script.sh` adds everything that is possible and make a commit. It takes two args: path to a ignore file and the message for the commit:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
git config --local core.excludesfile $1
git add .
git commit -m $2
git config --local --unset core.excludesfile

$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        a
        b
        script.sh

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Commit everything that is possible (b and script.sh)

```
$ ./script.sh ~/.gitignore1 "First"
[master (root-commit) 5908fbd] First
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 b
 create mode 100644 script.sh
```

Commit everything that is possible (a)

```
$ ./script.sh ~/.gitignore2 "Second"
[master d6c06d8] Second
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
```

Comment: Will this change the `.gitignore` file for all pushes?

Comment: You can set this variable in the begining of your script and then unset it in the end, as you can see, there is used the `local` scope, so it works only for the current project.

Comment: This is not working, I updated my question to show the function I use with your code, and the files are not being ignored.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't need an equal sign

Comment: How do I reset it, I'm getting this error when trying to switch - `warning: core.excludesfile has multiple values`

Comment: `--local` was throwing an error so I switched to `--global`.  This still did not work so I reposted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337124/global-gitignore-file-not-working

Comment: Obviously you need to execute `git config --local --unset core.excludesfile` before running the script. Thats why you have these problems. Your global config conflicts with your local one.

Comment: I can't run that command, even by itself, I still get an error when I do - `warning: core.excludesfile has multiple values`

Comment: put `git config --local --unset core.excludesfile` in the begining of your script. It doesn't produce any error code, so the script will work good regardless if the `core.excludesfiles` variable has already been set or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add files to `.git/info/exclude` to exclude custom files whose patterns you don't want to put in `.gitignore`.