# Why does global .gitignore file not appear to work_?

Tags: git, macos, github

cade_galt

I use this small script to do a push.

```
p1() {
  git config --global core.excludesfile /Users/a/root/.gitignore1
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "foo"
  git push test master
  git config --global --unset core.excludesfile
  echo $a
}
```

However the files are not being ignored.

**.gitignore1**

```
.DS_Store
web/
```

Comment: Why can't you use a local `.gitignore` file instead?

Comment: Show the content of `/Users/a/root/.gitignore1`, does it exist?

Comment: The local `.gitignore` will just work without using `git config core.excludefile ...`.

Comment: What files are not ignored (files tracked by git will not be ignored), what is the output from `git status`?

Comment: What is the main task that you wished to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. It is not how Git was designed to be used.  By taking items on and off the .gitignore file, you are leaving cached items that Git continues to use.

This will cause all sorts of problems.